# ALIZE platform installation

Tags: voice-recognition, speaker

Could you, please, help me with this error. I'm trying to install alize-1.4 on Ubuntu from this site http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/download_en.html. But I get such error at the end

```
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/admin-pc/alize/src' 
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1 cp: cannot stat `src/libalize.a': No
such file or directory
```

Maybe someone of you used ALIZE code?

Thanks

Comment: The last 3 lines you posted are not enough to understand the problem which happened above those three lines. Please share full build log, not just last 3 lines. You can upload the log to a file sharing resource and give here a link.

Comment: Sorry, here is full build log file https://www.box.com/s/t4cf0r82sv0y5hpqciuq. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, according to the log the real error is

```
g++ -DPACKAGE_NAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_TARNAME=\"\" -DPACKAGE_VERSION=\"\" -DPACKAGE_STRING=\"\" -DPACKAGE_BUGREPORT=\"\" -DPACKAGE_URL=\"\" -DPACKAGE=\"libalize\" -DVERSION=\"0.0\" -DSTDC_HEADERS=1 -DHAVE_SYS_TYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_SYS_STAT_H=1 -DHAVE_STDLIB_H=1 -DHAVE_STRING_H=1 -DHAVE_MEMORY_H=1 -DHAVE_STRINGS_H=1 -DHAVE_INTTYPES_H=1 -DHAVE_STDINT_H=1 -DHAVE_UNISTD_H=1 -DHAVE_DLFCN_H=1 -DLT_OBJDIR=\".libs/\" -I.     -O3 -ffast-math -Wall -march=pentium4 -MT SegServerFileWriter.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/SegServerFileWriter.Tpo -c -o SegServerFileWriter.o SegServerFileWriter.cpp
SegServerFileWriter.cpp: In member function void alize::SegServerFileWriter::writeSegServerTrs(const alize::SegServer&):
SegServerFileWriter.cpp:299: error: 'qsort' was not declared in this scope
make[1]: *** [SegServerFileWriter.o] Error 1
```

This type of error is quite common when you compile old style C++ projects with newer gcc due to the restrictions of the new compiler

The easy way would be just to checkout the latest code with subversion, it has all such issues fixed:

```
 svn checkout http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/svn/ALIZE/trunk/
```

Or to add `#include <cstdlib>` into the file header to import the qsort declaration.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now I want to run feature normalization tool. I write this command ./NormFeat.exe --config NormFeat3.cfg But it doesn't work. Could you, please, help me? How can I get NormFeat.exe file?

Comment: It should be just normfeat, not normfeat.exe on Unix. And you need to checkout LIA_RAL in addition to Alize, see http://mistral.univ-avignon.fr/download_en.html

http://alize.univ-avignon.fr/svn/LIA_RAL/trunk/

Comment: I installed LIA_RAL. But when I write 
__root@admin-pc-desktop:/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL# NormFeatExe='/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL/bin/NormFeat'

root@admin-pc-desktop:/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL# NormFeatConfig='/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL/LIA_SpkDet/NormFeat/test/cfg/NormFeat.cfg'

root@admin-pc-desktop:/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL# NormFeatExe --config NormFeatConfig --InputFeatureFilename test1__

I get this error
__NormFeatExe: command not found__

Comment: What you are doing is not quite correct for Unix command line, try just 'home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL/bin/NormFeat --config NormFeatConfig --InputFeatureFilename test1'

Comment: Thanks. Normalization works now. But when I try to open it in MS Word I get weird symbols. Is it possible? And when I write '/home/admin-pc/LIA_RAL/bin/EnergyDetector --config EnergyDetector.cfg --InputFeatureFilename test1' I get this error: https://www.box.com/s/lcitjsgf9eesqtknp95w
Could you, please, help me?
Here is my EnergyDetector.cfg file https://www.box.com/s/cvbh4szjcmkfeexapmw5

Comment: You have case mismatch, the parameter is inputFeatureFilename, not inputFeatureFileName. Please fix your config file. Next time just try to read the message, it's usually very helpful.